# IP is changing when sending UDP packet with spoofed IP in C Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: sockets, ubuntu-12.04, spoofing

I am writing a code in C, Eclipse, Ubuntu 12.04. I am opening a socket and sending UDP packets from spoofed source IP.
When I run the code in the virtual machine (the same code, Eclipse, Ubuntu version) everything was OK, but now when I try to run it on real Ubuntu machine it doesn't work properly.

```
bzero(&spoof_addr, sizeof(spoof_addr));
spoof_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
spoof_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVERPORT);
if (inet_aton("192.168.160.240", &spoof_addr.sin_addr)==0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "inet_aton() failed\n");
    exit(1);
}    

if ((sockfd_spoofed = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP))==-1)
        err("socket");
     bind(sockfd_spoofed,(struct sockaddr*)&spoof_addr,sizeof(spoof_addr));

    //Send the packet
    if (sendto(sockfd_spoofed, buf_port, 5, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&dest_addr, sizeof(dest_addr))==-1)
```

The problem is Ubuntu/kernel changes my source IP to real IP of the only interface I have.
Eclipse runs without any errors or warnings. So I understand, that IP is changing after the packet leaves the Eclipse application.
I tried to add additional IP like this:
     ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.160.240 netmask 255.255.255.0 up    (this worked in virtual machine) but doesn't affect real PC.

Answer (score 2):

When you send UDP packets, and the UDP stack in the kernel is always going to set the headers to the correct values.

If you want more control over what is sent, you need to use raw sockets.

[wikipedia raw sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_socket)

[linux man page for raw sockest](http://linux.die.net/man/7/raw)

Be aware this is hard and requires root privileges.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are right. Now I use raw socket and it works. It is strange it worked in virtual machine.

Comment: @yael if this answered your question, I'd appreciate an upvote and if you would click the checkbox next to the answer to accept it.  This will also help other people know this is an answer to this problem if they look at it in the future.